# MVC 4 EntityConnection Dynamic Schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to map a database schema at runtime to when building a dynamic EntityConnection?

I have a function below which connects to our internal database, to return the necessary credentials:

```
public string GetEntityConnection(int? portalId)
{
    const string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

    var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

    var portalConnections = _portalAdminEntities.Portal_connections.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Portal_ID == portalId);

    if (portalConnections != null)
    {
        var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = portalConnections.PortalServer,
            InitialCatalog = portalConnections.PortalDatabase,
            UserID = portalConnections.PortalUsername,
            Password = portalConnections.PortalPassword,
            PersistSecurityInfo = true
        };

        var providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = providerName,
            ProviderConnectionString = providerString,
            Metadata = @"res://*/Models.PortalAdmin.csdl|res://*/Models.PortalAdmin.ssdl|res://*/Models.PortalAdmin.msl"
        };
    }

    return entityBuilder.ToString();
}
```

I then call the function like so to upload data to our remote server:

```
using (var portalAdminEntities = new PortalAdminEntities(new EntityConnection(_df.GetEntityConnection(model.portalId))))
{
    portalAdminEntities.InsertPageDetails(model.pageId, portalId, model.title, model.content);
}
```

Despite successfully connection to our remote server, the actual stored procedure cannot be found, due to a difference in database schema on the remote server.

I believe the issue to be related to Models.PortalAdmin.msl, as this file was generated by Visual Studio 2010 when creating the Entity Framework to connect to our internal database, which therefore stores the schema. In this case our internal schema is `dbo`, whereas externally we use `somethingelse` (controlled by our external hosting provider).

So can the `msl` file be bypassed or schema defined when connecting to perform remote tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation found that the Visual Studio 2010 generated csdl, msdl and ssdl files need to be imported at runtime and manipulated> My updated solution below allows a dynamic entity connection to be created at runtime using a schema other than dbo:

```
public EntityConnection GetEntityConnection(int? portalId, string modelName)
{
    var serverName = "";
    var databaseName = "";
    var username = "";
    var password = "";

    var portalConnections = _portalAdminEntities.Portal_connections.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Portal_ID == portalId);

    if (portalConnections != null)
    {
        serverName = portalConnections.PortalServer;
        databaseName = portalConnections.PortalDatabase;
        username = portalConnections.PortalUsername;
        password = portalConnections.PortalPassword;
    }

    Func<string, Stream> generateStream = extension => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(string.Concat(modelName, extension));

    Action<IEnumerable<Stream>> disposeCollection = streams =>
    {
        if (streams == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var stream in streams.Where(stream => stream != null))
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    };

    var conceptualReader = generateStream(".csdl");
    var mappingReader = generateStream(".msl");
    var storageReader = generateStream(".ssdl");

    if (conceptualReader == null || mappingReader == null || storageReader == null)
    {
        disposeCollection(new[] { conceptualReader, mappingReader, storageReader });

        return null;
    }

    var storageXml = XElement.Load(storageReader);

    foreach (var entitySet in storageXml.Descendants())
    {
        var schemaAttribute = entitySet.Attributes("Schema").FirstOrDefault();

        if (schemaAttribute != null)
        {
            schemaAttribute.SetValue(databaseName);
        }
    }

    storageXml.CreateReader();

    var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace();

    var storageCollection = new StoreItemCollection(new[] { storageXml.CreateReader() });
    var conceptualCollection = new EdmItemCollection(new[] { XmlReader.Create(conceptualReader) });
    var mappingCollection = new StorageMappingItemCollection(conceptualCollection, storageCollection, new[] { XmlReader.Create(mappingReader) });

    workspace.RegisterItemCollection(conceptualCollection);
    workspace.RegisterItemCollection(storageCollection);
    workspace.RegisterItemCollection(mappingCollection);

    const string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

    var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = serverName,
        InitialCatalog = databaseName,
        UserID = username,
        Password = password,
        PersistSecurityInfo = true
    };

    var providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

    var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Provider = providerName,
        ProviderConnectionString = providerString,
        Metadata = string.Format(@"res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl", modelName)
    };

    var connection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(entityBuilder.Provider).CreateConnection();

    if (connection == null)
    {
        disposeCollection(new[] { conceptualReader, mappingReader, storageReader });

        return null;
    }

    connection.ConnectionString = entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;

    return new EntityConnection(workspace, connection);
}

using (var portalAdminEntities = new PortalAdminEntities(_df.GetEntityConnection(model.Portal_ID, Models.PortalAdmin")))
{
    portalAdminEntities.InsertPageDetails(model.pageId, portalId, model.title, model.content);
}
```

I hope this proves useful to others :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd ever want to bypass the msl or any of the generated files.  You can manually remove the dbo. from the msl, ssdl and csdl if you want or through the Ef model properties which means the db will work in any environment.

Comment: Really??? I didn't realise, haven't seen anything on the web about editing the msl file to remove the scheme reference. Many thanks, I'll investigate further.

Comment: I've tried opening up the edmx and removing the dbo reference from the Database Schema Name, but I get an error saying `Property value is not valid. Value cannot be null.` am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to set a property named Metadata Artifact Processing to 'Copy to Output directory'.  This will cause the generation of 3 files .msl, .ssdl and .csdl.   You should be able to manually edit the ssdl and remove the schema attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I did this, found a new Models folder contained within the bin folder with three files as you correctly stated, I opened the ssdl file in Notepad and removed the schema tag but now get the error `Unable to load the specified metadata resource.`